# Behavior of Conditional Operator in arithmetic operation

Tags: c, gcc

This question is about how conditional operator works in arithmetic operation and assignment statement.

Tested on gcc, arm-gcc.

```
//gcc 5.4.0

#include  <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    int temp=70;
    int t2=temp%100 + temp>99?2000:1900;
    printf("t2=%d",t2);
    return 0;
}
//This code returns answer 2000.
//gcc 5.4.0

#include  <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    int temp=70;
    int t2=temp%100 + (temp>99?2000:1900);
    printf("t2=%d",t2);
    return 0;
}
//This code returns answer 1970.
//gcc 5.4.0

#include  <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    int temp=70;
    int t2= temp>99?2000:1900 +temp%100;
    printf("t2=%d",t2);
    return 0;
}
// Answer is 1970
//gcc 5.4.0

#include  <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    int temp=70;
    int t2= 5+ temp>99?2000:1900 +temp%100;
    printf("t2=%d",t2);
    return 0;
}
// Answer is, 1970!
```

Once arithmetic statement encounters conditional operation, it ignores left part of statement. (I think anything after conditional operation in order of execution is ignored)

Also, we can mitigate this by using round brackets (), or having conditional operation at left most.
Can anyone explain this behavior? Is there any undefined behavior problem introduced by using conditional operation inside arithmetic statement?

Also surprised that this is not being asked before. If it is, please provide link.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: "Round brackets", I love it! You just added a new word to my vocabulary :)

Comment: The ternary operator follows the standard [operator precedence and associativity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), like any other operator.

Comment: They are called "parentheses", or "parens" for short.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `t2` is dependent on the operator precedence of the modulus `%`, addition `+` and ternary `?:` operators.

You can find the full list of C operator precedence by following [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) link.

In your case, the modulus operator has highest precedence, followed by addition and then the ternary operator.

Comment: @ChinmayJoshi, if you're happy with my answer please accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

Case 1: `int t2=temp%100 + temp>99?2000:1900;` be re-written for clarity as: `int t2=(temp%100 + temp)>99 ? 2000 : 1900;`

And that expression: `temp%100 + temp` is 140, which is bigger than 99, so the expression has value `2000`.

---

Case 2: `int t2=temp%100 + (temp>99?2000:1900);`

`temp` is not GreaterThan `99`, so the expression is `1900`, and added to `temp%100`, resulting in `1970`

---

Case 3: `int t2= temp>99?2000:1900 +temp%100;`

`temp` is not GreaterThan `99`, so the expression is `1900+70`, resulting in 1970

---

This is all Order of Operations; just as `*` and `/` take precedence over `+` and `-`, all operators have a precedence.